# Filling empty tibble empty cells on a matching condition of other cells

Tags: r, function, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

Ok. I have an example tibble below.

In the rows #9, 10, 11 we have the same `Номер заказа`. I need to set the same `ID корзины` for the all three like it is in the first case - "141330".
I was trying case_when and if_else, but seems I need to write function here...

```r
library(data.table)
library(tidyverse)

orders <- fread("~/Downloads/orders.csv", select = c("id", "Номер заказа", "Статус", "ID корзины", "ФР", "Сумма"),
                colClasses = list(character = c("id", "Номер заказа", "Статус", "ID корзины"),
                                  numeric = c("ФР", "Сумма")), dec = ",")


orders1 <- orders %>% 
  mutate(`Номер заказа` = stringr::str_remove(`Номер заказа`, ".*Р-")) %>%
  group_by(id, `Номер заказа`, Статус) %>%
  summarise(`ID корзины`, ФР = sum(ФР, na.rm = T), Сумма = sum(Сумма, na.rm = T))

orders1
#> # A tibble: 12 x 6
#> # Groups:   id, Номер заказа [12]
#>    id    `Номер заказа` Статус                          `ID корзины`    ФР Сумма
#>    <chr> <chr>          <chr>                           <chr>        <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1 11061 180618-11061   Отменен                         "66843"       66.0   218
#>  2 20752 260219-20752   Отменен                         "98537"        0     928
#>  3 24450 040619-24450   Отменен                         "108330"       0     -51
#>  4 24552 060619-24552   Отменен                         "108516"     -53.8   -22
#>  5 33064 241219-33064   Отменен                         "134157"       0     260
#>  6 35137 070220-35137   Доставлен                       ""           492.   1520
#>  7 36117 290220-36117   Передан на склад                "141275"       0     326
#>  8 36142 290220-36142   Передан на склад                "138181"       0     999
#>  9 36147 010320-36147   Передан на склад                "141330"       0    1025
#> 10 36155 010320-36147   Передан на отгрузку (отправлен… ""             0     335
#> 11 36157 010320-36147   Передан на отгрузку (отправлен… ""             0     592
#> 12 4548  4361           Доставлен                       "41096"      472.   1678
```

<sup>Created on 2020-03-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You can fill latest values in missing rows using `zoo` package.

Here is an example.

```
a <- c(1,2,"","",3,"","")

> a
[1] "1" "2" ""  ""  "3" ""  "" 

a[a==""] <- NA

> a
[1] "1" "2" NA  NA  "3" NA  NA

library(zoo)

na.locf(a)
[1] "1" "2" "2" "2" "3" "3" "3"
```

This can fill values according to the latest non-NA values.
Maybe you can call your `ID корзины` and perform the same.

In your case,

```
library(zoo)
orders1$ID корзины[orders1$ID корзины==""] <- NA

orders1$ID корзины <- na.locf[orders1$ID корзины]
```

Comment: I don't need to fill ALL missing values, just where values of `Номер заказа` are the same

Answer (score 0):

If all values are number, and there is no conflict of values with the same `Номер заказа` and different `ID корзины`, one option is to use use `group_by()` and `mutate()` to solve this:

```
 orders2 <- orders1 %>% group_by(`Номер заказа`) %>%
            mutate(`ID корзины` = median( `ID корзины`, na.rm = T)) %>%
            ungroup()
```

This way, all the rows with the same `Номер заказа` will have the same `ID корзины` (as the median of them, in case there is more than one.)